# assembly language bootable disk editor/compiler?

Tags: assembly, editor, diskimage, bootable

recently I have been involved with a few assembly projects with my friends
but me being the primary programmer. compiling codes, and putting them on a disk with a separate computer has become a tedious and annoying task. I want to know
if there is such an application that I can put on a disk, boot up on it ,and have the ability to edit, interpret, compile/decompile assembly codes on the blank computer. because I can't find anything of the sort.
like a sort of bootable IDE for assembly.

Comment: Boot up some OS that has a live mode from usb or cd.

Comment: It's still much easier to use VirtualBox or QEMU.

Comment: Why do (you think) you need a blank computer for this? Btw it sounds odd that you resort to "decompile" assembly code. Normally one keeps the (assembler) source so it won't be need to decompile anything.